# Vaadin Tree Right-To-Left Alignment

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

By default the Vaadin [Tree](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/tree) component is left aligned: the roots are on the left and the children are moving to the right.

```
+ root
|---child
|-----grandchild
|-----grandchild
```

Is it possible to set the alignment to `right-to-left`: the roots are on the right and the children are moving to the left? Also the expand/collapse triangles should be on the right.

```
           root+
       child---|
grandchild-----|
grandchild-----|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can do it with styles. I wrote simple solution for Valo theme (another theme may have other styles). Hope I didn't forget anything.

```
.v-tree.rtl-tree {
  direction: rtl;
  .v-tree-node-caption {
    span {
      padding-left: 28px;
      text-align: right;
    }
    .v-icon {
      padding-left: 0;
    }
  }
  .v-icon + span {
    margin-right: 7px;
  }
  .v-tree-node::before {
    right: 19px;
  }
  .v-tree-node.v-tree-node-root::before {
    right: 0; // special for root node
  }
  .v-tree-node-children {
    padding-right: 19px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @user3449857 for the answer. I tried your styles and it changes the direction of the icons and of the items caption to `right-to-left`. But the leading triangles (expand/collapse indicators) are on the left side. This also should be on the right. Is it possible using CSS?

Comment: @DoNot May be your arrows are drawn on the different way. There are two selectors related to arrow position: `.v-tree-node::before` and `.v-tree-node.v-tree-node-root::before` (special for root nodes). So, if you don't have these pseudo elements, styles won't work. You can add your tree styles, and I will check them.

Comment: I tried again and it worked. The first time I had some other rules which conflict with your rules. Thanks!